# PHPMailer - Error Data not accepted using SMTP Gmail

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send email using SMTP Google but receive following eror 
 But what makes me confuse is this error occured intermitent, sometime the email successfully sent sometime i got this error

```
2016-03-11 08:00:50 SMTP ERROR: DATA END command failed: 2016-03-11 08:00:50    SMTP Error: data not accepted. 2016-03-11 08:00:50  CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2016-03-11 08:01:50  SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed:
phpmailerException Object
(
    [message:protected] => SMTP Error: data not accepted.
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 2
    [file:protected] => /home/anekapaperaindah/public_html/application/libraries/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php
    [line:protected] => 1492
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/anekapaperaindah/public_html/application/libraries/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php
                    [line] => 1300
                    [function] => smtpSend
                    [class] => PHPMailer
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
```

Below is the config for send email

```
$destino = $this->input->post('email');
                        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
                        $mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
                        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
                                    //  $mail->SMTPDebug = true;
                        $mail->IsSMTP(); // we are going to use SMTP
                        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; // enabled SMTP authentication
                        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";  // prefix for secure protocol to connect to the server
                        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";     // setting GMail as our SMTP server
                        $mail->Port       = 465;                   // SMTP port to connect to GMail
                        $mail->Username   = 'admin@anekapaperaindah.id';  // user email address
                        $mail->Password   = '********';           // password in GMail
                        $mail->SetFrom($get_email, $company_name);  //Who is sending the email
                        $mail->AddReplyTo($get_email, $company_name);   //email address that receives the response
                        $mail->Subject    = "Reset Password";
                        $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
                        $mail->Priority = 1;
                        $mail->Debugoutput = 'echo';
                        $mail->Timeout = 60;
                        //$mail->SMTPDebug=3;
                        //$mail->Body      = 'tet';;
                        $mail->isHTML(true);  
                        $mail->MsgHTML($msg); 
                        $mail->AddAddress($destino);
```

Really appeciate for Any suggestion or helps to fix this issue.
Been almost 2 days but still no luck

Content of email is HTML format which declared in variable $msg.

```
$msg = $this->load->view('front/notif_reset_password',$data,true);
```

Below is the html of that view

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="560" style="background:#ffffff;border:1px solid #cccccc;margin-top:10px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tbody><tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse:collapse">

<table border="0" cellpadding="23" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="background:#ffffff;border-bottom-width:0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tbody><tr>
<td style="border-collapse:collapse;border-bottom: 3px solid #081071;text-align:center;vertical-align:top" align="left" valign="top">

<img src="http://i650.photobucket.com/albums/uu229/bayu288/logo-aneka_1.png" border="0" alt=" photo logo-aneka.png"/>
<!--<a href="" style="color:#a30046;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:none" target="_blank">
<img alt="Aneka" height="80" src="http://i650.photobucket.com/albums/uu229/images/logo-aneka.png" style="border:0;min-height:auto;line-height:100%;max-width:302px;outline:none;text-decoration:none" width="302" >
</a>-->
</td>

</tr>
</tbody></table>

</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse:collapse">

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="560">
<tbody><tr>
<td valign="top" style="background:#ffffff;border-collapse:collapse" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<table border="0" cellpadding="23" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody><tr>
<td valign="top" style="border-collapse:collapse">
<div style="color:#808080;font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;line-height:150%;text-align:left" align="left">
<div style="color:#808080;font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;line-height:150%;margin:5px 2px;text-align:left" align="left"></div>
<p>Selamat Datang Di PT. Aneka Papera Indah,</p>

<div style="color:#808080;font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;line-height:150%;margin:5px 2px;text-align:left" align="left">


<p><b>Your Detail Information</b></p>
<table style="color:#808080;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;line-height:150%;text-align:left">

  <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><?php echo $email ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Kode Verifikasi</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><?php echo $token_id ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="background:#ffffff;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #cccccc;font-size:12px;margin-bottom:25px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

</table>
<table width="100%" style="background:#def0e5;color:#808080;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;line-height:150%;margin-bottom:40px;text-align:left" bgcolor="#DEF0E5">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="border-collapse:collapse;text-align:right;vertical-align:middle" align="right" valign="middle">
<span style="background:#DEF0E5;display:block;min-height:26px;"></span>
</td>
<td style="border-collapse:collapse;vertical-align:middle;text-align: center;" valign="middle">
<p>
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'isms_front_aneka_ctrl/reset_password.html?email='.$email.'&key='.$token_id ?>">Reset Password Anda</a>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div style="color:#808080;font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;line-height:150%;margin:5px 2px;text-align:left" align="left">
<div style="color:#808080;font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;line-height:150%;text-align:left" align="left">
<br>

Terima kasih atas perhatian dan kepercayaan Anda.
<br>
<br>
<a href="" style="color:#081071;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:none" target="_blank">
<strong>PT Aneka Papera Indah</strong>
</a>
<div style="color:#808080;font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;line-height:150%;text-align:left" align="left">
<div style="color:inherit;font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;line-height:150%;text-align:left;text-decoration:none" align="left">
<?php echo $address ?>
<br>
<?php echo $city ?>
</div>
<span><?php echo $phone ?></span>
-
<span><?php echo $fax ?></span>

</div>
<span>
E-mail :
<a href="mailto:cs@aneka.com" style="color:#a30046;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:underline" target="_blank">cs@anekapaperindah.com</a>
</span>
</div>
<br>

</div>
</div>

</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse:collapse">

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="560" style="background:#ffffff;border-top-width:0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tbody><tr>
<td valign="top" style="border-collapse:collapse">

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody><tr>
<td width="23px" style="border-collapse:collapse"></td>
<td valign="middle" style="background:#ffffff;border-collapse:collapse;border:0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<div style="border-top-color:#e8e8e8;border-top-style:solid;border-top-width:1px;color:#707070;font-family:Arial;font-size:10px;line-height:150%;text-align:left" align="left">
&nbsp;
<br>
Follow us
<a href="<?php echo $twitter ?>" style="color:#a30046;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none" target="_blank">@aneka</a>
&nbsp;
<font color="#CCCCCC"></font>
| &nbsp;Like us on&nbsp;
<a href="<?php echo $facebook ?>" style="color:#a30046;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none" target="_blank">Facebook.</a>
</div>
<br>
</td>
<td width="23px" style="border-collapse:collapse"></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</td>
</tr>



<tr><td><table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="560" style="border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody><tr>
<td valign="top" style="border-collapse:collapse">

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody><tr>
<td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-collapse:collapse;color:#999;display:block;font-family:Arial;font-size:10px;font-weight:normal;line-height:130%">
<div>

</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>

</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Looks like some filter on the server side decides that the content of that email should not get accepted. So the question is: what is that content? Could you please post it? Thanks!

Comment: Might be worth trying to set the `SetFrom` to the email you're logging into as well rather than the user input.

Comment: @arkascha done...@Matt SetFrom value pretty much the same just like Username. And i've already tried by set value for SetFrom still no luck

Comment: I also experience such behavior. My code worked for several years without problem, but today under heavy load I get this error occasionally

Answer (score 1):

Gmail disables SMTP by default and prefers access through their API. You have to enable support for "less secure" applications. See https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257?rd=1

Comment: I've  already done that too and also still no luck, But what makes me more confuse is this error occured intermitent, sometime the email successfully sent sometime i got this error

Comment: gmail tends to have quite drastic anti spam measurements. you might have been temporarily blacklisted. It would be helpful to get the actual error message the SMTP server sent. Google usually sends a helpful message with each error code. If "Data is not accepted" is the actual message, there might be something wrong with your encoding and depending on your mail's content it goes through or not.

Answer (score 0):

We get this error from PHPMailer when we hit our **Gmail send limits**.

You can check if it's the same thing happening to you by going into Gmail and trying to manually send an email. In our case that displays the more helpful error message about sending limits.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en